# The right way to delete a cell in dynamic array of pointers

Tags: c, pointers, structure, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

in my current homework project I have built a dynamic pointers array, where each pointer points on a structure of data with some strings inside (indicating Users). I am trying to find the proper way to remove a specific cell (or User) inside the array, without any heap memory issues.

So I've been trying to `free` the specific cell and then shift the other cells, so there will be no empty cell left. After that, I tried to "cut" the last cell which is currently empty, with `realloc` the array by -1. Please see comments in the code where I describe my problem.

```
User** deleteMale(User** pMaleArr, int *maleArrSize, User *onlineUser)
{
    int i,j;
    //for each array element check if the username matches to the 
    // connected user
    for (i = 0;i < *maleArrSize;i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(pMaleArr[i]->userName, onlineUser->userName) ==0) 
        {
            //when the user is found, free all fields of the struct
            freeUserFields(onlineUser);
            //check if it's the last array cell
            if (i != *maleArrSize - 1)
            {
                //shift cells
                for (j = i;j < *maleArrSize;j++)
                {
                    pMaleArr[j] = pMaleArr[j + 1];

                }//free the last cell
                free(pMaleArr[*maleArrSize-1]); //I'm getting a problem here because now the 2 last cells of the array have the same pointer adress.
            }
            //remove the last cell
            pMaleArr = (User **)realloc(pMaleArr, (*maleArrSize 
- 1)*sizeof(User*));
            if (pMaleArr == NULL)
            {
                if (*maleArrSize != 1)
                {
                    printf(MA_FAILED);
                    exit(1);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    *maleArrSize -= 1;
    return pMaleArr;
}

void freeUserFields(User *person)
{
    if (person != NULL)
    {
        //free all fields
        free(person->firstName);
        free(person->lastName);
        free(person->age);
        free(person->userName);
        free(person->userPassword);
        free(person->about);
        free(person->hobbies);
        //free node itself
        free(person);
    }
```

}

So as I noticed above, when I try to `free` the last cell, in order to delete it afterwards, it deletes also the (last-1) cell because I copied their adresses. I can't find another way to shift the cells in this case. Can I get an advice on how to handle it properly? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a serious problem in this piece of code:

```
    if (strcmp(pMaleArr[i]->userName, onlineUser->userName) ==0) 
    {
        //when the user is found, free all fields of the struct
        freeUserFields(onlineUser);                  // NOOO !!!
```

You are freeing fields on a struct that was passed to control the username, while you should only access the content of the `*pMaleArr` array. You should write:

```
    if (strcmp(pMaleArr[i]->userName, onlineUser->userName) ==0) 
    {
        //when the user is found, free all fields of the struct
        freeUserFields(pMaleArr[i]);
```

And you should not free the last cell. You do not free a pointer, but where it points to. What is pointed to by last pointer is now pointed by previous pointer and has to be kept. So that other part should be:

```
        if (i != *maleArrSize - 1)
        {
            //shift cells
            for (j = i;j < *maleArrSize;j++)
            {
                pMaleArr[j] = pMaleArr[j + 1];

            }//just ignore the last cell
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Regarding the first issue - I guess it was a spelling error O:-)

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to free the last cell, because you're keeping a pointer to that user.

Just remove the second free.

Also, the second loop should go up to `j < *maleArrSize -1`.

Comment: Hi @Marco, I get your point. So in other words, it's safe to delete a cell without freeing it because this address is still in use in other cell.
So when I will want to free all the array, I'll free that address, right?

Comment: That's right: you free an address only when you don't need the information that's stored there. Please upvote my answer if it's been useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have added notes on you code, hope this helps:

```
     //check if it's the last array cell
        if (i != *maleArrSize - 1)
        {
            //shift cells
            for (j = i;j < *maleArrSize-1;j++)
            {
                pMaleArr[j] = pMaleArr[j + 1];/* you need till size -1 because of[j+1]*/

            }//free the last cell
            free(pMaleArr[*maleArrSize-1]); //I'm getting a problem here because now the 2 last cells of the array have the same pointer adress.
        }
        //remove the last cell- here if the cell to remove was the last one you don't free its inner allocations.
        pMaleArr = (User **)realloc(pMaleArr, (*maleArrSize
```

Comment: Thank you! but doesn't it mean that I have deleted a pointer to that memory but the memory is still left there? I have to free all the memory.

Comment: well that depends on how you allocated the memory to begin with. if your array is an array of pointers and each pointer is malloced a struct then you do need to free it as well after freeing the inner struct mallocs and the space on heap for the last pointer in your array is freed by the realloc